# How to send to a web-server request for performing js-function under c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, http, post, request

First of all, english is my foreign language.
Under C# I am trying to send POST http request to a forvo.com (bank with pronounces of words) to get an audio file (stream) with pronunciation of some word. For example, I want to click button1 and listen pronunciation of word "stack" that I got from forvo.com site. For this I have a code:

```
 using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["LANGUAGE_ID"] = "39";
                data["WORD"] = "someword"; //this tag doesnt make effect to request
                //var response = wb.UploadValues("http://www.forvo.com/search/", "POST", data);
                byte[] responseArray = wb.UploadValues("http://www.forvo.com/search/data", "POST", data);
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\fi2le.html", responseArray);  
            }
```

With that actions I am trying to get a link to an audio-file. After looking to a file.html I see these strings

```
<a href="/word/data/#en" title="Listen data pronunciation" onclick="Play(38630,'ODk3NTU5NS8zOS84OTc1NTk1XzM5XzE3MjNfMjI4MjAubXAz','ODk3NTU5NS8zOS84OTc1NTk1XzM5XzE3MjNfMjI4MjAub2dn');return false;" rel="nofollow"><img src="/_presentation/img/ico_play.gif" alt="data pronunciation" id="play_38630" width="23" height="23" /></a><a href="/word/data/#en" title="data pronunciations">data</a> and others looking similiar.
```

What can I do with these js-functions or what is it?

I am a newbie in web-programming, and know nothing about js.
and I know forvo.com has its own API for tasks like mine, but I'm trying make it without API.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're not wanting to use the API that is provided precisely to allow you to access these services?

Comment: yes. 1- api has a restrictions (500 requests per day to an account) - not good if i am gonna share programm. 2 - I wanna to know how to do it with no-built-in ways, to learn new skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what's going on here, the click on the icon triggers the Javascript `Play()` function.

This function decodes those base 64-encoded values passed to it, and uses them to find the relevant file to play, and whether you are using a browser capable of understanding an `audio` element (HTML5) in which to play it, or, if not, it creates a Flash player in which to play it.

The second and third arguments to the `Play()` function are, as mentioned, the base-64 encoded URIs of the files to play. They can be decoded quite simply as follows (example is for a console application):

```
static void Main()
    {
      string base64a = "ODk3NTU5NS8zOS84OTc1NTk1XzM5XzE3MjNfMjI4MjAubXAz";
      string base64b = "ODk3NTU5NS8zOS84OTc1NTk1XzM5XzE3MjNfMjI4MjAub2dn";

      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64a)));
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64b)));

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Should you run this, you'll find that they convert to:

```
8975595/39/8975595_39_1723_22820.mp3
8975595/39/8975595_39_1723_22820.ogg
```

There's some logic in the `Play` function to determine which one to use, but ultimately, I end up playing the following file:

```
http://audio.forvo.com/mp3/8975595/39/8975595_39_1723_22820.mp3
```

This work needs to be done in Javascript, as much is dependent upon the browser or device that is making the request, as highlighted above (e.g. HTML5 capability)

I must add, though, that whilst this hopefully explains what is going on, I doubt it would be of any use as a solution; as a paywall is in existence at 500 requests, I'd have thought that they would be on the lookout for multiple requests from the same IP address over a period of time, and would block any such address that was avoiding payment.